# unexpected element PricedLocation

Tags: xml, xsd, sabre

Calling Sabre `PassengerDetailsRQ` in test environment we received unexpected tags like `'PricedLocation'` inside `TransactionInfo`. But also other unexpected tags. For example:

```
<PricedLocation countryCode='IT'>MIL</PricedLocation>
<TicketedLocation countryCode='IT'>MIL</TicketedLocation>
<PricingQualifiers>
  <Qualifier>
    <ActionCode>WP</ActionCode>
  </Qualifier>
  <Qualifier mergeAllowed='true'>
    <ActionCode>P</ActionCode>
    <Data>1ADT</Data>
  </Qualifier>
  <Qualifier>
    <ActionCode>RQ</ActionCode>
  </Qualifier>
</PricingQualifiers>
<TicketByDate>2023-07-13T00:00:00</TicketByDate>
```

We use the version 3.4.0.

Does someone know why?

Looking the xsd we should receive only those tags:

```
<xs:element name="TransactionInfo">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Data at PQ transaction
            level</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="CreateDateTime" type="xs:dateTime">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>System Date/time the PQ was created
                        Ref: DM0Z_65_CLDB and
                        DM0Z_65_CLTB</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="UpdateDateTime" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>System Date/time the PQ was updated.
                        Ref: DM0Z_65_ULDB and
                        DM0Z_65_ULTB</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="LastDateToPurchase" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Time Stamp for Last Date by when the PQ has to be purchased. Ref:DM0Z_40_TMST</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="LocalCreateDateTime" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Local Create Date/time the PQ was updated.
                        Ref: SR06PQ-20_CLDB/CTIM</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="LocalUpdateDateTime" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Local Update Date/time the PQ was updated.
                        Ref: SR06PQ-20_ULDB/ULTB</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="ExpiryDateTime" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Price quote expiry Date/time the PQ. Ref: DM0Z_40_PXDT/DM0Z_40_PXTM</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="InputEntry" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Entry made to update the price quote.
                        Ref: DM0Z_60_TYPE
                        #DM0Z_60_PRI
                        #DM0Z_60_MAN</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:minLength value="1" />
                        <xs:maxLength value="255" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: What is creating the XML payload?